# TinyMCE get font size of selection

Tags: tinymce, font-size, tinymce-4

I'm currently building my own custom toolbar for TinyMCE, getting & setting the formats through the JS API. 
For example, I can set the selected text to bold like this:

```
this._editor.formatter.toggle('bold');`
```

Afterwards I can get the format and set the state of my bold-button accordingly like this when the selection changes:

```
this.isBold = this._editor.formatter.match('bold');
```

To support font sizes I have a dropdown which applies the correct font size on change:

```
this._editor.formatter.apply('fontsize', {value: this.fontSize});
```

But now I need to be able to read the fontsize when the selection changes and I don't know how to achieve this. **How can I read the fontsize of the current selection?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I'm trying to match the format of the selected node against a list of supported font sizes.

```
const supportedFontSizes = ['10px', '11px', '12px', '14px', '16px', '18px', '20px', '24px'];
const defaultFontSize = '16px';
let foundFontSize = false;
let fontSize;

supportedFontSizes.some(size => {
  if (editor.formatter.match('fontsize', { value: size })) {
    fontSize = size;
    foundFontSize = true;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

if (!foundFontSize) {
  fontSize = defaultFontSize;
}
```